# Access Denied Error After Configuring "Require Login"

Tags: federated-authentication, authentication, login

I'm having a problem with Sitecore 10. I made a page that should only be seen by people who log in. I used the `require login` setting for this page from the security editor. But it's not working the way I thought it would.

Here's what's happening:

I log into Sitecore and go to the page.
Instead of the page, I get an `access denied` message.
It looks like Sitecore doesn't know I'm logged in. It says the user is `extranet\anonymous`.

Even debugging the page after logged in the Sitecore.Context.User.Name is `extranet\anonymous`

[image]

I found something interesting. When I remove this part from `identityserver.xml`, the problem goes away

```
<ApiScopes>
    <SitecoreProfileApi>
      <Name>sitecore.profile.api</Name>
      <DisplayName>Sitecore Profile API Scope</DisplayName>
    </SitecoreProfileApi>
</ApiScopes>

<Scopes>
    <SitecoreProfileApi>sitecore.profile.api</SitecoreProfileApi>
</Scopes>
```

Why does this fix the issue? Is it okay to just remove these lines, or is there a better way to do this? After removing the code, the azure ad login button is missing.